# How to refresh CustomUI controls in loop logic?

Tags: excel, vba

I want use custom UIRibbon as indicator. I know invalidate, invalidatecontrol method to refresh custom UIRibbon,and usually it works.But in loop logic,it does not work.

All code is this.

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="IRibbonUI_onLoad">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab id="customtab1" insertBeforeMso="TabHome" label="customtab1">
<group id="customgroup1" label="customgroup1">
<labelControl id="label1" label="Time"/>
<labelControl id="label2" getLabel="label2_getLabel"/>
</group>
<group id="customgroup2" label="customgroup2">
<button id="button1" size="large" getLabel="button1_getLabel" getImage="button1_getImage" onAction="button1_click"/>
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

```vb
Dim bButtonClicked As Boolean
Public MyRibbon As IRibbonUI
Public strfilename1 As String
Public stop_flag As Boolean
Public RibbonInvalidate As Boolean
Public v_label2 As String
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    Dim lngRbnPtr                   As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
    Dim lngRbnPtr                   As Long


#End If
Sub IRibbonUI_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set MyRibbon = ribbon
#If Win64 Then
  Dim lngRbnPtr                   As LongPtr
#Else
  Dim lngRbnPtr                   As Long
#End If

lngRbnPtr = ObjPtr(ribbon)
'save pointer to registry for safe keeping
SaveSetting "Myapp", "Ribbon", "RibbonPointer", lngRbnPtr
End Sub

Sub label2_getLabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = ThisWorkbook.xl_label2
End Sub

Sub button1_getImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case bButtonClicked
        Case False
            returnedVal = "PlayFromPage"
        Case True
            returnedVal = "PauseAllSharedSpaces"
    End Select
End Sub

Sub button1_getlabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case bButtonClicked
        Case False
            returnedVal = "Start"
        Case True
            returnedVal = "Pause"
    End Select
End Sub

Sub button1_click(control As IRibbonControl)
    Select Case bButtonClicked
    Case True
        stop_flag = True
        bButtonClicked = False
    Case Else
        stop_flag = False
        bButtonClicked = True
        MsgBox "Start"
        Call testloop
    End Select
    strfilename1 = Format(Time(), "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub


Public Sub testloop()
  Do Until stop_flag = True
    strfilename1 = Format(Time(), "hh:mm:ss")
    ThisWorkbook.xl_label2 = strfilename1
    If MyRibbon Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "set"
        lngRbnPtr = GetSetting("Myapp", "Ribbon", "RibbonPointer")
        CopyMemory MyRibbon, lngRbnPtr, 4
    End If
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = strfilename1
    DoEvents
    MyRibbon.Invalidate
Loop
MsgBox "End"
End Sub





#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
Private Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
  Dim p As LongPtr
#Else
Private Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As Long) As Object
  Dim p As Long
#End If
  Dim ribbonObj As Object
  
  CopyMemory ribbonObj, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer)
  Set GetRibbon = ribbonObj
  p = 0: CopyMemory ribbonObj, p, LenB(p) 
End Function
```

I made sample xlms,Clicking another tab and back, control is refreshed.I want to Know how to refrewsh custom UIribbon in loop logic.  After clicking start,just display Time. Cell's time is always refresh,but Ribbon's label is not. But I guess invalidate is working.Because clicking another tab and back, Time is refreshed only once. And cicking stop,last time is refreshed.your text In such case,Doevents affects well, but never refreshed.I want refresh Label's time same as cells. I searched anywhere, but still can't find. I guess there is noway that I want?